# Get count and volume candle in OnCalculate

Tags: metatrader4, metatrader5

I would like to know how to pick up the candle volume and a "counter" the candle in question. When I caught the `tick_volume[rates_total]` is different with the volume presented to me when I use the indicator "Volume". Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`tick_volume[rates_total]` should be causing `array out of range` error if called from OnCalculate(). `tick_volume[rates_total - 1]` should be showing the tick volume of the latest candle unless `AS_SERIES` flag is set for `tick_volume`. Use `ArraySetAsSeries` to find out. If it is set, use `tick_volume[0]` to get the latest candle's tick volume.